# condensing an async method into a one liner

Tags: graphql, python-asyncio

I'm working on some async code for subscriptions / web sockets and have the following code after some effort.  This in itself is functional.

```py
@type(name="Subscription")
class ContactsSubscription:
    @subscription
    async def company(self, info: Info, pk: str) -> AsyncGenerator[CompanyType, None]:
        async for i in model_subscribe_publisher(info=info, pk=pk, model=Company):
            yield i
```

The part where I'm struggling is discovering how I can rewrite certain aspects to shorten this code even more and remove the repetitiveness out of the code for each model declaration through my 40-odd models in the app.

My goals would be to condense this into something like:

```py
@type(name="Subscription")
class ContactsSubscrption:
    company: AsyncGenerator[CompanyType, None] = model_subscribe_publisher(Company)
```

I've seen this done in the same strawberry library, for queries:

```py
@type(name="Query")
class ContactsQuery:
    company: CompanyType = node()
```

I fail to understand the magic that makes this work. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: "type" is already overloaded with means in Python up to 3.11, and now even more, as a special syntax as part of the typing mechanism, in Python 3.12  - are you sure you are _loading_ it with even more meaning in a project by overwriting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "magic" to make this work - the syntax you are using is that of a class decorator.

As you don't post the code for your `type` decorator, there is no way pointing what can be done - but it is a callable that gets the class, after ready, as a parameter: all one has to do is, inside the decorator call, to iterate over te class members and the class `__annotations__`, find out which members it want to place as new or replace, instantiate the new objects and assign then back to their names.

(That said, as I commented above, `type` is a poor choice for a class decorator name because it already has 3 different meanings in Python)

Or, if you don't want to change the class decorator, in your "desired" code, you just have to write a method that returns the `model_subscribe_publisher` as you want it:

ex.:

```
def subscriber_factory(model):
     async def subscriber_model_publisher(self, info, pk):
            async for item in model_subscribe_publisher(info=info, pk=pk, model=model):
                yield item
     return subscriber_model_publisher

@type(name="Subscription")
class ContactsSubscrption:
    company: AsyncGenerator[CompanyType, None] = subscriber_factory(Company)
```

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  The type comes out of a graphql library called strawberry.  The source for this type decorator is here: https://t.ly/TRzzu

The choices of names is unfortunately not mine, merely trying to follow the style set out by the package.  

I have tried to wrap the async method in `subscriber_factory`, unfortunately it doesnt seem to return an actual result: `TypeError: Subscription field must return AsyncIterable. Received: None.`. Adding some logging shows that the async method doesnt seem to get called.